# Como forçar a versão de um plugin do maven?

Tags: maven

Eu tenho um projeto maven tal, que na hora de rodar o `build`, um plugin A é executado. Este plugin A depende de um plugin B que é puxado, que por sua vez depende de um plugin C.

Acontece que este plugin C está em uma versão X que tem um bug irritante, e eu quero forçar o maven a usar uma versão Y.

Além disso, eu não utilizo o plugin C diretamente. Também nem sei qual é o plugin B que a utiliza. Mas se eu deleto ele do repositório e tento compilar offline, o maven reclama.

O que posso fazer para forçar o maven a usar a versão desejada?

Comment: O estimado companheiro que votou contra a minha questão, poderia por gentileza explicar o que você acha que há de errado com ela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar utilizar a seção `pluginManagement` para fixar a versão desejada do plugin:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>C</artifactId>
      <version>Y</version>
    </plugin>       
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Dê uma olhada na [documentação](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin%5FManagement) (em inglês) para mais informações.

Answer (score 3):

Existem duas opções:

1. adicione a versão desejada como dependência direta do seu projeto, assim ela terá prioridade na resolução de dependências.
2. Exclua a dependência incorreta. Exemplo:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jtidy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
        <version>r938</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-tools-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```